# clustering based on multiple attributes (preferably using Java)

Tags: clustering

Hello and thank you in advance :)
For context, i've been willing to fiddle with machine learning for a while and think i might have found a decent use case to start :

I have a set of objects Oi each depending on informations requests In , ex
O1(I1,I2,I3), O2(I1,I3,I4,I5)
my goal would be to make objects groups(each respecting a max size)  to minimise the number of total information requests made : we would only make one request for  I1 I2, I3 I4, I5  to handle O1 and O2 if they are grouped together.

- Do you think machine learning/clustering is well suited for this case ?
- Do you know a (preferably Java)  library that could be helpfull to do that ?

thank you very much

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.